# How do I copy specific text from one section into a new section?

Tags: xslt

I need to copy only the 2 `<iframe>` pieces in the section below into a new section. How would I do that using XSLT?

```
<section class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude" data-title="Resources" property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback">
      <p><i>MedEssentials (4th Ed.):</i> pp. 205</p>
      <p><i>First Aid (2019): </i> pp. 493.2</p>
      <p><i>First Aid (2018):</i> pp. 489.2</p>
      <p><i>First Aid (2017):</i> pp. 476.1</p>
      <iframe class="biodigital" height="500" src="https://human.biodigital.com/viewer/?be=3Ely&amp;ui-info=true&amp;ui-search=true&amp;ui-reset=true&amp;ui-fullscreen=true&amp;ui-nav=true&amp;ui-tools=true&amp;ui-help=true&amp;ui-chapter-list=true&amp;ui-label-list=true&amp;disable-scroll=false&amp;uaid=4j2yH"></iframe>
      <iframe class="armando" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8IlDew4QK1w?start=78"></iframe>
</section>
```

The snippet of code I have from my XSLT script is copying the whole section into the new section. How do I isolate just those 2 `<iframe>` lines and have them copy into the new section?

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Explanation']"> 
        <section>  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="following-sibling::xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Resources']"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Aren't you just missing `/xhtml:iframe` from the end of your `select`? (`select="following-sibling::xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Resources']/xhtml:iframe"`)

Comment: Also note that since you're doing an `xsl:apply-templates`, other templates might match those iframes and change the output. (It's not doing an actual copy like `xsl:copy-of` would.)

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much!